# File upload progress not showing on WordPress Media Library (VPS with CPanel)

Tags: wordpress, server, upload, cpanel

I'm currently facing the following problem - when uploading files by using WordPress default "Media Library", the upload progress is not shown. The progress bar just freezes until the file gets uploaded.

[File upload progress not shown on Media Library (screen 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnBTk.png)

[File upload progress not shown on Media Library (screen 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OGhO.png)

I'm using VPS with CPanel (on Centos 7) without Nginx, PHP 7.4

Any ideas what could be wrong? Feel free to ask if additional information is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! Turns out I was looking in completely different direction. This bug was caused by website theme, which registered a service worker. Service worker caused this problem to happen.